# Session in a class

Tags: c#, asp.net, properties, getter-setter

I have a class object where i m storing a list of questions in. I want to save this object in a session.
I can do this:

```
JobApplication _application;
_application = new JobApplication(1);

Session["Application"] = _application;
```

i can also get the session by this:

```
JobApplication obj = (JobApplication)Session["Application"];
```

So, I want to pass in the class object( JobApplication _application;) into a class and set the session in the class and return a session.
Can i set and get like  i am doing?

but i would rather pass in the object into my session class and set it and get it from there.
I am not sure how to use sessions in get and set . I am fairly new to C#

Comment: You already can get/set from session (better use properties). What more do you need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public class JobApplicantSession
{
    public JobApplication Application 
    {
        get
        {
            return (JobApplication)HttpContext.Current.Session["Application"];
        }
        set
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session["Application"] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. How can i get the session from another class?

Answer (score 0):

Please do like below

```
 public class JobApplicantSession
    {
       public JobApplicantSession(JobApplication  _application )
       {
         Session["Application"] = _application;
       }

        public JobApplication  GetApplication()
        {
         JobApplication _application = Session["Application"];
         return _application ;
        }

    }
```

Also make sure that `JobApplication` class has the attribute `[Serializable]`

Comment: the 'id' parameter is not doing anything inside. Better the method name should be GetSessionApplication()

Comment: Sorry. I missed that while copying. Updated the answer

Comment: Just make another method 'SetSessionApplication(JobApplication application)' in similar fashion

Comment: Can you clarify it a bit more? Still I dont understand what you want :(